# 3DS Max Spline snapping to straight line

Tags: 3ds-max

When modifying a curve being close to a straight line 3DS max 'snaps' the curve into a straight line:

[image: Unwanted Spline snap]

The question is how to resolve this so the on screen output is as expected, i.e. a smooth spline.

Comment: Note your "question" doe not ask a question therefore your answer is not understandable. Please edit. Also operating your 3D applicateion is not really on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of composing the question I discovered the answer.

Under the "Interpolation" menu of the modifiers tab, turn off the "Optimize" option.

[image]

I posted this since I couldn't find this info elsewhere and hopes it helps someone else.